# Laplace transform: The meaning of $s$ and its link to Fourier Transforms.

Tags: complex-numbers, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I've recently been introduced to Laplace transforms, and my understanding so far is that it's a continuous analogue to a Summation of a power series, that maps injectively a function $f(t)$ to another function of a new variable $s$, $F(s)$.

My question though is that if we take $$\int_0 ^\infty a(t)x
^t dt$$And then make the substitution $-s = ln(t)$ and that the coeffecients $a(t)$ are generated by the function $f(t)$ we get:
$$\int_0 ^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt.$$

My confusion comes from looking up and finding that $s$ is apparently of the form $\sigma + i\omega$, but given that $-s$ is $\ln(x)$ and the limits are $0$ to $\infty$, that surely means that $-s \in R$? Or have I made a mistake in my reasoning somewhere.

The second part of my question is with regards to $s$ again, in that from what I've seen of Fourier transforms [hasn't come in syllabus yet] it just seems like a Laplace transform with purely imaginary $s$. What is / was the mathematical motivation for this?

Comment: With $s=a+bi$, the bilateral Laplace transform of $f(t)$ is the Fourier transform of $e^{-at}f(t)$. One motivation is that the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ might not exist, but the exponential modulation by $e^{-at}$ might lead to a convergent integral. So the Laplace transform might exist in cases where the Fourier transform doesn't exist; it is thus applicable to a wider class of problems.

Comment: As for your confusion regarding $-s=\ln x$, that is just a motivating heuristic to try to make the integral look like a continuous version of a power series. The *definition* of the Laplace transform allows $s$ to be an arbitrary complex number. The real reason Laplace and Fourier transforms are useful has to do with complex exponentials being eigenfunctions of translation operators (and thus eigenfunctions of operators that commute with translation, such as time-invariant differential operators), not with power series.

Comment: Thanks, if you were to put this as an answer I'd accept it